# Can't set 2dsphere index with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to set 2dsphere index for mongoose geospatial but for some reasons I am failing to do it, I have tried everything but still can't get it.

Here is my schema and location field.

```
loc: {
     type: { type: String, default: "Point" },
     coordinates: { type: [Number] }
},
causeSchema.index({ "loc": "2dsphere" });
```

And the error

unable to find index for $geoNear query

If anyone knows the solution please share here. Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you managed to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I actually just found the solution. The code is totally correct.

Basically, I was trying to set a `2dsphere` index, just like you:

```
mySchema.index({ startLocation: '2dsphere' });
```

All of my documents present in the collection had this `startLocation` field set to a GeoJSON value, in particular a `Point`...**except for just one**! That one did not have any value for the `startLocation` field, therefore I could not set the index! I just deleted that document and yes, the index was there!

### How did I come up to this?

I was reading the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#sparse-property) and I found this:

> If a document lacks a 2dsphere index field (or the field is null or an
>   empty array), MongoDB does not add an entry for the document to the
>   index

I think it's correlated to this problem, and it made me think that maybe one document was lacking the value for `startLocation`, and in fact that was the reason.